# when vscode.window.showInputBox focus is coming for the first time, the focus is not in the input box

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am displaying an inputbox with the following code.

```js
await vscode.window.showInputBox({
                    placeHolder: placeHolderStr,
                    prompt: promptStr,
                    ignoreFocusOut: true,
                    value:params
                });
```

But whenever the Input box appears the focus is going to terminal window, not in the input box. How to set the focus on the inputbox by default.

Comment: Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) into your question post.